# How to use model types between projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, service-layer

I'm using service layer lattern, and my solution contains three projects:

- Core
- Service
- UI

In my controller In the UI-project I have the following code:

```
 public ActionResult AddSpotifyAlbums(List<SpotifyAlbums> albums)
        {
            _profileService.AddSpotifyAlbums(albums);
            return Json(new { data = albums });
        }
```

SpotifyAlbums in `List<SpotifyAlbums>` Is a Model in my UI project. It looks like this:

```
  public class SpotifyAlbums
    {
        public string URI { get; set; }
        public int profileId { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, I'm using a service here, `_profileService`, to call a method that handles the saving of the albums.

But the type of the albums Is `SpotifyAlbums`. How should I do in my service when the model type of the albums is `SpotifyAlbums`?

I have tried to create a identical model in my Service-project, but it doesn't work. I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to
>   'soundyladder.Service.Models.SpotifyAlbums'

Comment: Put the model definitions in a Class Library project which is referenced by your other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot arbitrarily assign objects of different types to one another. Even though you give them the same name, they are independent entities.

Assuming the Service and UI projects reference your Core project, you can define the `SpotifyAlbums` class in your Core project and reference that class across your other layers.

Answer (score 0):

Bryan, you need to decide which module "owns" `SpotifyAlbum`. Decision needs to take in consideration data encapsulation, data access and data manipulation aspects. Is important to establish proper service references and get all modules using `SpotifyAlbum` instances to grab it from the module "owning" the `SpotifyAlbum`. Then all other modules would have proxy classes built from the references to "owning" module.

Answer (score 0):

I use the same design pattern (resource-based trusted subsystem).  I like to use a .dll that contains common code and shared models.  Then all projects reference that .dll for the model definitions.